# Switch on android device from adb

Tags: android, adb

Is there any way to switch on device from adb without pressing the switch on button of android device. I have adb installed and i did also try to put some adb commands but still not working

for eg : -

> adb reboot -p
>
> adb reboot

Comment: Communicating with an offline device, if adb don't detect it, I would guess not

Comment: This [android thread](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/22640/turn-phone-on-with-adb-or-fastboot) could inform you, but no a complete answer

Answer (score 0):

I believe not. If your phone is switched off, the phone's adb interface will not be running.

Comment: I know about that but then is there any other way instead of opening(dismantle) the device.